# Displaying multiple Google Maps markers on a Visualforce page

Tags: javascript, html5, google-maps, salesforce-apex

I hope this is the right board for this. I am a novice programmer and I am trying to learn how to write better code. I have a visualforce page with a very long Javascript script in the middle of it to display a Google Map. The code is entirely inside of a single function, but I cannot figure out a cleaner way to break it up. What are some ways that I can write code cleaner and better?

```
<apex:page docType="html-5.0" standardController="Property__c" extensions="ControllerJSGeo">

<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=XXXXXXXXXXX&callback=initMap&sensor=false"></script>


<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<apex:includeScript value="https://c.xxx.visual.force.com/resource/1466633623000/connection"/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/soap/ajax/24.0/apex.js"></script> 


<script type="text/javascript"> 

$(document).ready(function() {

//set map variables

var myOptions = {
    zoom: 18,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID,
    mapTypeControl: true,
    scrollwheel: false
}

var map;
var marker;
var marker2;
var propLat;
var propLong;

var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
var address = "{!Property__c.Property_Address__c}, " + "{!Property__c.City__c}, " + "{!Property__c.State__c} " + "{!Property__c.Zip_Postal_Code__c}}";

var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    content: "<b>{!Property__c.Name}</b><br>{!Property__c.Property_Address__c}<br>{!Property__c.City__c}, {!Property__c.State__c} {!Property__c.Zip_Postal_Code__c}"
    });       


//get the Tenant Subtype, removing any unsafe characters such as quotes
var dirtyST="{!Property__c.Tenant_Sub_Type__c}";
var subtype=cleanQuotes(dirtyST);

function cleanQuotes(unsafe) {
    return unsafe
    .replace(/'/g,"\\'");
}

    //get geocoordinates of each property            
    geocoder.geocode( { address: address}, function(results, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK && results.length) {
            if (status != google.maps.GeocoderStatus.ZERO_RESULTS) {

            //create map
            map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), myOptions);
            map.setTilt(45);


            //center map
            map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);

            //create marker
            marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: results[0].geometry.location,
                map: map,
                title: "{!Property__c.Name}"
            });

            //add listeners
            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
                infowindow.open(map,marker);
            });

            google.maps.event.addListener(infowindow, 'closeclick', function() {
                map.setCenter(marker.getPosition()); 
            });

            //if the geocoord fields are blank, create new Salesforce object from record, and set the geocoord fields to geocoordinates from result
            propLat=results[0].geometry.location.lat();
            propLong=results[0].geometry.location.lng();

            var pLat="{!Property__c.GeoCoord__latitude__s}";
            var pLng="{!Property__c.GeoCoord__longitude__s}";


            if((!pLat||!pLng||pLat==""||pLng=="")&&(!address||address!="")){
                var newRecords = []; 
                var c = new sforce.SObject("Property__c"); 
                var pId="{!Property__c.Id}";
                c.Id=pId;
                c.GeoCoord__latitude__s=propLat;
                c.GeoCoord__longitude__s=propLong;

                //Then update the record and reload the page
                newRecords.push(c); 
                result = sforce.connection.update(newRecords); 
                reload();
            }

            else{
                console.log("geocoding failed for"+pId+"::"+address+"...Address is null or geocoords already exist");
            }

            //Get the properties returned by the Controller, and create a Marker object for each one 
            var geosArray = [];
            var geosObject={};
            var geos=[];
            var idy=0;
            <apex:repeat value="{!getgeoList}" var="m">
            geosArray[idy++]='{!m}';
            </apex:repeat>

            for (var g = 0; g < geosArray.length; ++g) {
                geosObject=JSON.parse(geosArray[g]);
                geos.push(geosObject);
            }

            for (var i = 0; i < geos.length; ++i) {
                var myLatLng = {lat: geos[i].GeoCoord__c.latitude, lng: geos[i].GeoCoord__c.longitude};
                var html="<b>Nearby {!Property__c.Tenant_Sub_Type__c}:</b><br /><br /></b><a href='/"+geos[i].Id+"'target='_blank'>"+geos[i].Name+"</a><i><br />"+geos[i].Property_Address_Full__c+"</i><br />";
                createMarker(myLatLng, html);
            }

            function createMarker(latlng, html) {
                marker2 = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: latlng,
                    map: map,
                    icon:'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/blue-dot.png'
                });

                addInfo(marker2,html);
            }

            function addInfo(marker2,html) {
                var infowindow2 = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                    content: html                         
                });

            google.maps.event.addListener(marker2, 'click', function() {
                infowindow2.open(map, marker2);
                });
            }



//Brackets for OK results
            } 
        } 

        else {
            $('#map').css({'height' : '15px'});
            $('#map').html("Oops! {!Property__c.Name}'s billing address could not be found, please make sure the address is correct.");
            resizeIframe();
        }
    });

// resize iFrame 
    var me = window.name;
    if (me) {
        var iframes = parent.document.getElementsByName(me);
        if (iframes && iframes.length == 1) {
            height = document.body.offsetHeight;
            iframes[0].style.height = height + "px";
        }
    }


});



</script>

<style>
#map {
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size:12px;
  line-height:normal !important;
  height:800px;
  background:transparent;
}
</style>

</head>

<body>
<div id="map"></div> 
<apex:form id="distance">
    <apex:outputText >Find nearby properties within&nbsp;</apex:outputText>
    <apex:input value="{!dist}" label="X" type="number"/>
    <apex:outputText >&nbsp;miles&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</apex:outputText>
    <apex:commandButton value="Submit" action="{!getgeoList}"/>
</apex:form>

</body>




<br /><br />
<apex:outputText >====DEBUG====</apex:outputText><br />
<apex:outputText >Distance:</apex:outputText>
<apex:outputText >{!dist}</apex:outputText><br /><br />
<apex:outputText >{!getgeoList}</apex:outputText>

<apex:form >
    <apex:actionFunction action="{!reload}" name="reload"/>
</apex:form>


</apex:page>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, there are many things you can clean up just in your javascript.

- Always develop in strict mode.
- Always use Immediately Invoked Function Executions.
- [You might not need jQuery](http://youmightnotneedjquery.com/)
- If you decide you *do* need `jQuery`, always use `noConflict`.
- Always use [JSLint](http://jslint.com/)

  - It mostly dings you for trailing space here
- You can one-line your `var` declarations.

And specific to the Salesforce platform:

- All strings used in your Javascript should be encoded with `JSENCODE`.

  - You don't need to reinvent the wheel with your `cleanQuotes` function, and it will likely delay or fail security review.
- When passing arrays between server side and client side, use serialization and parsing instead of mixing markup into your scripts with an `<apex:repeat>` tag.

Using the above, your code might look more like:

```
(function (w, $) {
    "use strict";
    $(function () {
        var map, marker, marker2, propLat, propLong,
            myOptions = {...},
            geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder(),
            address = '{!JSENCODE(Property__c.Property_Address__c) & JSENCODE(...) & etc.}';
        // and other properties

        geocoder.geocode(..., function () {
            // this function can be declared separately
            // instead of anonymously
        });
    });
}(window, jQuery.noConflict()));
```

You can also break out some of the functions you have declared into top level `var` declarations.

```
(function (w, $) {
    "use strict";
    $(function () {
        var /*other variables*/,
            createMarker = function (latlng, html) {
                // logic here
            },
            addInfo = function (marker2, html) {
                // logic here
            };
    });
}(window, jQuery.noConflict()));
```

You might also consider geocoding your data in a batch process, at which point you can use the **out of the box** [`<apex:map>`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_map.htm) and [`<apex:mapMarker>`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_mapMarker.htm) tags. They are supported for addresses you haven't geocoded yet, but you only get ten markers in that case. It looks like there is now also a tag for [`<apex:mapInfoWindow>`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_mapInfoWindow.htm)

Comment: Thanks. Very helpful! So <apex:mapMarker> will work even without the geocoordinates?

Comment: Yes, it will work, but you can only use ten of them in that case.

Comment: I haven't used JSENCODE before. I had to change your code to: `{!JSENCODE(Property__c.Property_Address__c)}` etc... to get it to work.

Comment: Good catch, yes you still need merge syntax. Post updated.